# How do I extract just the last directory from a ZIP archive using 7zip in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a ZIP archive with a deep directory structure. I want to unpack just the last directory ("Package"). And I want all of it's sub-directories and content. I don't know exactly what will be in there, but I want it all.

Let's say the archive looks like this

```
package.zip
  folder1\
    folder2\
      folder3\
        Package\
          PackageTmp\
```

I started writing this script using the 7zip CLI in a Windows batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (DIR *.zip /B /A:-D) DO CALL :EXTRACT %%i
GOTO :EOF

:EXTRACT
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :EOF
SET zipfile=%1
SET folder=%zipfile:~0,-4%
7za.exe x %zipfile% -o%folder% -y PackageTmp*
GOTO :EOF
```

7zip always tells me: No files to process.

Comment: The question is salvageable, it doesn't need to be closed if @ChristianGK comes back and adds some details! For instance, what is the output of the script you started? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Seriously, this is the only question this user has asked, give him a chance! The question is legit.

Comment: Sorry for confusing and imperfect question. Now it should be clear.

Comment: No worries, you just needed a little help! And now you have an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the -r unzip option and also add the backticks to the for loop, see below.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR *.zip /B /A:-D`) DO CALL :EXTRACT %%i
GOTO :EOF

:EXTRACT
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :EOF
SET zipfile=%1
SET folder=%zipfile:~0,-4%
7za.exe x %zipfile% -o%folder% -y -r PackageTmp*
GOTO :EOF
```

Backticks are used to execute the command in between them. You can only use them if you add `usebackq` in the options of the for loop.

Executing a command and looping over the results can also be done in the following (more old-fashioned and limited) way with single quotes.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR *.zip /B /A:-D') DO CALL :EXTRACT %%i
```

See dos command `for /?` for more info.

Comment: When i add -r i also get the folder structure befor PackageTmp*

Comment: You're right. I cannot find a way to extract the PackageTmp* without its parent folders. You have to move them upwards yourself (by the batch script) and delete the parent folders.

Comment: What do the backticks do? Are they escape characters or something? Could you just wrap the statement in single or double quotes? (Please add any clarifying comments to the body of your answer!)